# How do I get a distinct value of items in a list of object or structure?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List. This collection holds an object containing the properties of a class.
I want a distinct value of list with respect to any specific property of a class. I have attached some sample code; please check & let me know if you guys have any solutions:

```
class Test
{
    public string firstname{get;set;}
    public string lastname{get;set;}
}

class Usetheaboveclass
{
    Test objTest=new Test();
    List<Test> lstTest=new List<Test>();

    objTest.firstname="test";
    objTest.lastname="testing";

    //Now i want a distinct value with respect to lastname.if i use 
     lstTest=lstTest.Distinct().Tolist();

    //It will process according to all properties.    
}
```

Can you suggest me a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach.

```
var distinct = lstTest.GroupBy(item => item.lastname).Select(item => item.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to do this for one property, override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `Test`. These are what `Distinct()` uses to define duplicates.

If you need to do this for multiple properties, define an `IEqualityComparer` (the usage is documented in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Or , you can implement a custom comparer

```
    public class LastNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
    {
        public bool Equals(Test x, Test y)
        {
            if (x == null)
                return y == null;
            return x.lastname == y.lastname;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Test obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;
            return obj.lastname.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Then , use it like

```
lstTest = lstTest.Distinct(new LastNameComparer()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use overloaded version of `Distinct`. Please see sample code below:

```
internal class Test
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

internal class LastNameComparer : IEqualityComparer<Test>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<Test>.Equals(Test x, Test y)
    {
        if (x.LastName == y.LastName)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<Test>.GetHashCode(Test obj)
    {
        return 0; // hashcode...
    }
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test objTest = new Test {FirstName = "Perry", LastName = "Joe"};
    Test objTest1 = new Test {FirstName = "Prince", LastName = "Joe"};
    Test objTest2 = new Test { FirstName = "Prince", LastName = "Jim" };

    List<Test> lstTest = new List<Test> {objTest, objTest1, objTest2};

    var distinct = lstTest.Distinct(new LastNameComparer()).ToList();

    foreach (var test in distinct)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test.LastName);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

Output of this will be:
Joe
Jim